# Fetching APIs while doing full-stack dev

Tags: javascript, spring, vue.js

I'm having trouble when I'm fetching my APIs that are created on the backend.
Mostly, I'm handling everything right on the good side but not when there is an error because the catch(error) method only catches the errors that are in the front-end server while my errors are coming from my back-end. My stack is mostly focused on VueJS and Spring Boot. I can give an example to clarify things.
For example, in the login. I have  a controller in my backend that contains JWT Creation

```
  JwtUtils jwtUtils;
  @PostMapping("/signin")
  public ResponseEntity<?> authenticateUser(@Valid @RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest) {

    Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginRequest.getEmail(), loginRequest.getPassword()));

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    String jwt = jwtUtils.generateJwtToken(authentication);
    
    UserDetailsImpl userDetails = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();    
    List<String> roles = userDetails.getAuthorities().stream()
        .map(item -> item.getAuthority())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtResponse(jwt, 
                         userDetails.getId(), 
                         userDetails.getEmail(), 
                         roles));
  }
```

on the front-end side I just consume this API.
So, I created a service on VueJS and that service is consumed by one of my views on a button click.
My service :

```
class AuthService{

    login(user){
        return  fetch("http://localhost:100/api/v1/auth/signin",
      {method : "POST",
      headers:{
        "Content-type" : "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email:user.email,
        password: user.password,
      }),
        
      }).then( response => response.json()).then(data =>{
          if (data.accessToken){
              localStorage.setItem('user',JSON.stringify(data))
          }
          return data})
      
    }
    logout(){
        localStorage.removeItem('user')
    }
}
export default new AuthService();
```

That service is called by my module (Vuex) in the localstore:

```
import AuthService from '../services/auth.service';
const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
const initialState = user
  ? { status: { loggedIn: true }, user }
  : { status: { loggedIn: false }, user: null };
export const auth = {
  namespaced: true,
  state: initialState,
  actions: {
    login({ commit }, user) {
      return AuthService.login(user).then(
        user => {
          commit('loginSuccess', user);
          return Promise.resolve(user);
        },
        error => {
          commit('loginFailure');
          return Promise.reject(error);
        }
      );
    },
    logout({ commit }) {
      AuthService.logout();
      commit('logout');
    },
    register({ commit }, user) {
      return AuthService.register(user).then(
        response => {
          commit('registerSuccess');
          return Promise.resolve(response.data);
        },
        error => {
          commit('registerFailure');
          return Promise.reject(error);
        }
      );
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    loginSuccess(state, user) {
      state.status.loggedIn = true;
      state.user = user;
    },
    loginFailure(state) {
      state.status.loggedIn = false;
      state.user = null;
    },
    logout(state) {
      state.status.loggedIn = false;
      state.user = null;
    },
    registerSuccess(state) {
      state.status.loggedIn = false;
    },
    registerFailure(state) {
      state.status.loggedIn = false;
    }
  }
};
```

And finally I have a view that would call the action, its basically a form that contains 2 input fields that are going to be passed to the backend for the post method.
Login.vue :

```
<template>
  <div id="nav">
    <NavBar/>
    <Loader  v-if="loading"/>
    <Form @clicked="onClickValue" :error="message"  />
  </div>

</template>
<script>
import NavBar from '../components/NavBar.vue'
import Form from '../components/Form.vue'
import Loader from '../components/Loader.vue'
export default {
  components:{
    NavBar,Form,Loader
  },
  data(){
    return{
      err:null,
      loading:false,
      message: '',
    }
  },
  methods : {
onClickValue(user) {
      this.loading = true;
      this.$store.dispatch("auth/login", user).then(
        () => {
          this.$router.push("/token");
        },
        (error) => {
          
          this.loading = false;
          this.message =
            (error.response &&
              error.data &&
              error.data.message) ||
            error.message ||
            error.toString();
        }
      );
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

I know that's alot of code but i'd like to explain my problem, basically I have some data on my server and when I fetch my API I want the user to login depending on his credentials. I know how to handle the errors but I don't know if that's the conventional way to do so. Generally I'd do this for example :
if res.status == 403 then (show error message on screen saying that the user is forbidden)
But is this how people handle errors that come from the backend ?? how should I do to handle my errors that are coming from the backend, is it an if statement or something else that should handle  it (is what i'm doing even secure? )?
basically here is an image of my page.
[Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRMg1.png)

Answer (score 0):

Its generally a good idea for the backend to handle the error messages, whenever they are generic or something specific, then on the frontend we just show that error message.
With this approach you wont struggle on the frontend in order to determinate which error code example: `if res.status == 403 || res.status === 404`.
The only thing you care about is error.message

Comment: yes but how can I know if there is even an error message. An API could either execute completely or not execute some features and handle an exception. When I actually think about that , the first thing that comes into my brain is a conditional if / else but as I said, is that how the good developers do? do they handle their errors with conditional statements or do they use some sort of built in methods inside of the framework that I don't even know to make the job on the frontend? One more thing, I always worry about javascript code injection.

Comment: Based on the HTTP/S status you can identify response is a success(200) or failed. Never do validation, error handling etc... on the UI(client) side. Create some reusable components on UI side and data will change dynamically based on the server response.